# Die and Coin events are dependent or not?

Tags: probability, independence, dice

Roll a die. Let $X$ denote the number on which the die lands on. Toss an unbiased coin $X$ times and let $Y$ denote the number of Heads.

Are $X$ and $Y$ independent or dependent events? If $X = i$ (for $1 \leq i \leq 6)$, then it does not decide the value of $Y$. It does limit the possibilities of $Y$ but does not determine it always.

Since $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, choose two events, say $X=2$ and $Y=0$.

I am trying to figure out how in [2. Independence, Question. 3](https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/stat110/files/strategic_practice_and_homework_2.pdf) whether an event determines the other(s) is associated with independence, is different from the case I wrote in the post here.

Comment: If it *limits the possibilities* then wouldn't it be stochastically dependent? Dependent does not mean "determines it always" in this context.

Comment: There is a strong association between the intuitive notion of independent events and the formal definition.  In fact, the adjective *independent* was (perhaps) motivated by intuition.  Anyway, from an intuitive viewpoint, clearly the coin flip results don't affect the die rolling, and vice-versa.

Comment: @user2661923 Right, so two events, say $X=2$ and $Y=0$ are supposed to be independent or not?

Comment: The distribution of the random variable $Y$ depends on the value of $X$ and the value of $X$ influences the possibilities for $Y$. So, the event "$Y=6$" is dependent on the result of $X$. In fact, it can only appear if $X=6$. The probability for $Y=0$ also depends on $X$, so the events are dependent.

Comment: @Peter Can you have a look at [2. Independence, Question. 3](https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/stat110/files/strategic_practice_and_homework_2.pdf) and tell me how whether an event determines the other(s) is associated with independence, is different from the case I wrote in the post here?

Comment: I didn't read your question closely enough.  Actually, the way that you define the variables $X$ and $Y$, the event $X = 2$ and the event $Y = 0$ are **not** independent events.  This is because you have the constraint that the number of coin flips will be $2$, when $X = 2$.  Clearly, the number of coin flips that come up heads will be affected by the number of times the coin is flipped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Saying $X$ and $Y$ are independent events means that for any $x,y$ we have $\Pr(X=x\text{ and }Y=y)=\Pr(X=x)\Pr(Y=y)$.

It's easy to see that can't be true here. Certainly $\Pr(X=2)>0$, and $\Pr(Y=4)>0$, but $\Pr(X=2\text{ and }Y=4)=0$.

By the same argument (for discrete random variables), if knowing $X$ limits the possibilities for $Y$ in any way then they cannot be independent. It certainly doesn't have to determine $Y$ completely.

Comment: That makes sense. So the key term in [2. Independence, Question. 3](https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/stat110/files/strategic_practice_and_homework_2.pdf) is "**completely** undetermined"?

Comment: @dictatemetokcus I would not phrase it that way.  Instead, I would either provide an intuitive definition, or a formal definition.  Intuitively, events A and B are independent, if the occurrence of event A does not affect the probability of event B occuring.  Formally, events A and B are independent if and only if $p(A|B) = p(A).$  Here, I am assuming that $p(A) \neq 0 \neq p(B).$

Comment: Applying the formal definition to the answer of Especially Lime, $p(Y = 4) \neq p(Y = 4  ~| ~X = 2).$

Comment: @dictatemetokcus yes, for the independence part it needs to be completely undetermined (in the sense that you get no information about C from A alone). For the dependence part, "completely determined" is not necessary, since even partially determined would do, but it is a useful hint because it is probably easier to find a completely rather than partially determined example.

Comment: Thanks Lime and @user2661923.

Comment: @dictatemetokcus If you like irony, $p(Y=0 ~| ~X = 2) \neq p(Y = 0).$  Here, $X = 2$ *partially* determines $Y$.

Comment: @user2661923 Haha sure.